# How to identify which SMS has got Delivery report in Android

Tags: android, sms, android-pendingintent

My application retrieves records from sqlite database and SMS to other application by merging the records based on the size of the record, i am intruble to identify which messages  have got the delivery report and which does'not . i am using BroadcastReceiver  on reciveMethods
but unfortunately i can't understand how to identify . i would love if any one of you suggest me the how to handle this problem. or any other better way

```
    public class MessageMangerActivity extends Activity {

    private String MessageBody;
    public  enum  MessageType
    {
           s,r,c
    }
    String ReceiverNumber="5556";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.messages);
         try {
            SubmitReportToServer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
    private void SubmitReportToServer() throws Exception {
       // MessageHandler messageHandler =new MessageHandler();
        //get Unsent Message
        ReportAdapter reportAdapter= new ReportAdapter(this);
        reportAdapter.open();

        /* Submit Received Item report*/
        Cursor  receivingResults;
        receivingResults=reportAdapter.FetchUnSentReceivingRecords();
        int i=0;
        if(receivingResults.getCount()!=-1) {
            while(receivingResults.moveToNext() ){
              MessageBody=MessageType.r + MessageBody +"|"+ receivingResults.getString(0)+"|" + receivingResults.getString(1)+"|"+receivingResults.getString(2)+"|"+
                      receivingResults.getString(3)+"|"+receivingResults.getString(4)+"|"+receivingResults.getString(5)+"|"+receivingResults.getString(6)+"|"+
                      receivingResults.getString(7)+"|" + receivingResults.getString(8)+"|"+ receivingResults.getString(9)+"|"+
                      receivingResults.getString(10)+"|"+receivingResults.getString(11)+",";
                i++;
                if (i > 1 )  { break;  }
            }
             sendSMS(ReceiverNumber,MessageBody);
            receivingResults.close();
        /* Submit Issued Item report*/
            Cursor  issueResults;
            issueResults=reportAdapter.FetchUnSentIssuedRecords();
            i=0;
            if(issueResults.getCount()!=-1) {
                while(issueResults.moveToNext() ){
                    MessageBody=MessageBody + ","+ issueResults.getExtras();
                    i++;
                    if (i > 3 )  { break;  }
                }
                sendSMS(ReceiverNumber,MessageBody);
                issueResults.close();
          }
        }
        /*Submit Vaccinated Children Report   */
            Cursor  childrenResults;
            childrenResults=reportAdapter.FetchUnSentVaccinatedChildrenRecords();
             i=0;
            if(childrenResults.getCount()!=-1) {
                while(childrenResults.moveToNext() ){
                    MessageBody=MessageBody + ","+ childrenResults.toString();
                    i++;
                    if (i > 3 )  { break;  }
                }
                sendSMS(ReceiverNumber,MessageBody);
                childrenResults.close();
    }
    }

    private void sendSMS(String receiverNumber, String messageBody) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                                //update Status
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

//—when the SMS has been delivered—
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    ``    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(receiverNumber, null, messageBody, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the data you need into the `PendingIntent` that will be broadcast when the delivery completes (or fails). When doing this you need to make sure that you create a unique `PendingIntent` for each message (you can do this by setting a unique ACTION on the `Intent`). Here's an example.

Instead of this:

```
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
```

Do this:

```
    long messageID = ... // This is the message ID, ie: the row ID in the SQLite database that uniquely identifies this message
    Intent deliveredIntent = new Intent(DELIVERED + messageID); // Use unique action string
    deliveredIntent.putExtra("messageID", messageID); // Add message ID as extra
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
           deliveredIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

When you register the receiver, be sure to use the correct `IntentFilter`:

```
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        ...
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED + messageID));
```

Now, when the delivery `Intent` is broadcast, you can get the data from it in `onReceive()` like this:

```
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        long messageID = arg1.getLongExtra("messageID", -1L);
        if (messageID != -1L) {
            // This is the message ID (row ID) of the message that was delivered
            ... do your processing here
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, i did what you have said but i can;t get see when the call back is fired up and my another emulator is not receiving any message. Did i miss something i have incorporated <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea if this works on emulators. I only know it works on real devices.

Comment: Instead of using a unique action to identify the message the intent is for, [I recommend setting a unique `requestAction`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7145956/194894)

Comment: this pending intent will only be called once when you send the sms. how do you identify when you are coming back as there is no MESSEGE_TYPE_DELIVERED in the TextBasedColumns? Do I need to take care of this manually?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO Sorry I do not understand your comment. Please try again or open a new question where you can explain more about what your problem is.