# Xamarin.Android: Detect SMS in SMS Delivered Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver, sms

In my `Xamarin.Android` app I send SMS using `SmsManager` class. I also get the delivery state using `PendingIntent` and `BroadcastReceiver`.
Everything works fine except that I can not tell which SMS is delivered when SMSDeliveredReceiver.OnReceive is called. Let's say I send two messages I just know that one of the sent messages is delivered. I need to know which SMS is delivered to do further processess. Please tell me how to create a bridge between SMS and Delivery.

Here is my code so far:

```
private PendingIntent piSent, piDelivered;
private BroadcastReceiver _smsSentBroadcastReceiver, _smsDeliveredBroadcastReceiver;

void SetUp()
{
    piSent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
    piDelivered = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

    _smsSentBroadcastReceiver = new SMSSentReceiver();
    _smsDeliveredBroadcastReceiver = new SMSDeliveredReceiver();

    RegisterReceiver(_smsSentBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
    RegisterReceiver(_smsDeliveredBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));

}

void Send(string number, string message)
{
    SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage(q.Number, null, q.Message, piSent, piDelivered);
}

[BroadcastReceiver(Exported = true)]
public class SMSDeliveredReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "SMSDeliveredReceiver.OnReceive", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        switch ((int)ResultCode)
        {
            case (int)Result.Ok:
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "SMS Delivered", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
            case (int)Result.Canceled:
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "SMS not delivered", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, ResultCode.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();

                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did you add permission and broadcast receiver in manifest file/

Comment: Yes @JaydeepPatel I've added permissions and I the broadcast receiver is called as I mentioned above, the question is how to detect the relative SMS? I get delivery but which of sent SMS is this delivery about?

Comment: @JaydeepPatel I know Java but that link actually won't help me. It is about Incoming Messages, my question is about Sent Messages. I Send a bunch of messages and want to check the DELIVERY STATUS of each message. The link you provided is about RECEIVING MESSAGES.

Comment: check here this might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17409640

Comment: Thanks @Jaydeep, with some modifications made, your latest link helped

Comment: always welcome!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Intent` to pass data in your `SendTextMessage` method, when your `SMSDeliveredReceiver.OnReceive` is called, you can tell which SMS is delivered by `intent.GetStringExtra("phone")`.

Here is the complete code and it works fine :

```
[Activity(Label = "SMSDemo", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private static string ACTION_SENT_SMS = "ACTION_SENT_SMS";

    private PendingIntent piSentd;
    SMSDeliveredReceiver mReceiver;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

        button.Click += (sender, e) =>
         {
             sendGroupSMS();
         };

        mReceiver = new SMSDeliveredReceiver();
        RegisterReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SENT_SMS));
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        UnregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    void sendGroupSMS()
    {
        List<string> phones = new List<string>();
        phones.Add("1*****2");
        phones.Add("1*****8");
        phones.Add("1*****9");

        SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.Default;
        foreach(string phone in phones)
        {
            Log.Debug("TAG", "Start sending sms to the phone " + phone);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SENT_SMS);
            intent.PutExtra("phone", phone);

            piSentd = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, phone.GetHashCode(), intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage(phone, null, "Test by York", piSentd, null);
        }

    }
}

[BroadcastReceiver(Exported = true)]
public class SMSDeliveredReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        string phone = intent.GetStringExtra("phone");
        switch ((int)ResultCode)
        {
            case (int)Result.Ok:
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "SMS Delivered" + phone + " success.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
            case (int)Result.Canceled:
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "SMS not delivered", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, ResultCode.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                break;
        }
    }

}
```